# Issue bearer token from IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, identityserver4

Is it possible to generate manually bearer token and return it if user is logged in successfully?

Here's my point of view:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login2(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            //TODO: Generate token
            string token = null; //TODO
            return Ok(token);
        }
    }
    return BadRequest("Invalid login attempt.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the identityserver4 authorize and token endpoints do already, why roll your own?

If you just want to implement a custom way to issue a JWT then I don't think identityserver4 is needed.